# Concatante PHP variables inside loop by a "Concatenating Assignment Operator", and Echo each output loop separately

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

With the "Concatenating Assignment Operator" I assigned in the loop two variables. I need to get each loop result separately. The problem is that I don't know why each next loop result is copied to each next loop result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php 
            $output = "";
            $number = "";
            $start = 0;
            $end = 5;

            $array = array();

            while($start <= $end) {
                $number = $start+=1;
                $output .= "1";
                $output .= "2";

                $array [] = $output;
            }
            echo json_encode(array (
                'output'=>$array,
            ));
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using this code, I get the output:

```
{"output":["12","1212","121212","12121212","1212121212","121212121212"]}
```

I'm working on making the output look like this:

```
{"output":["12","12","12","12","12","12"]}
```

Comment: You need to reset `$output` at the top of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always concatenating values to the $output, you never clear it, so the numbers are just continually added. All you need to do is change the first `$output .= "1";` in to a `$output = "1";` and that will have the effect of resetting `$output` to the one character ready to be concatenated with the second.

```
while($start <= $end) {
    $number = $start+=1;

    $output = "1";      // changed here
    $output .= "2";

    $array [] = $output;
}
```